# partial classes/partial class file

Tags: java, partial-classes

In C# .net there is a provision to have two different class files and make them a single class using the keyword partial keyword.this helps it to keep [for ex]UI and logic seperate.
of course we can have two classes to achieve this one for UI and other for logic.
Can this be achieved in java some how?

Comment: I found a way to separate an inner class into an external file, maybe it helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27284667/1190665

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### On source file splitting

No. Java source codes can not be split across multiple files.

From the [Wikipedia article *Comparison of Java and C Sharp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C_Sharp)

> The Sun Microsystems Java compiler requires that a source file name must match the only public class inside it, while C# allows multiple public classes in the same file, and puts no restrictions on the file name. C# 2.0 and later allows a class definition to be split into several files, by using the partial keyword in the source code. In Java, a public class will always be in its own source file. In C#, source code files and logical units separation are not tightly related.

---

#### On separating logic and UI into their own classes

The two classes approach is a *much* better solution than the one-class-two-source approach in this case, because the separation is enforced in the design, not just physical separation in the source codes.

#### See also

- [Separation of logic and UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584831/separation-of-logic-and-ui)
- [oo question - mixing controller logic and business logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978624/oo-question-mixing-controller-logic-and-business-logic)
- [Why is good UI design so hard for some Developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514083/why-is-good-ui-design-so-hard-for-some-developers)

Comment: @polygenelubricants
 thanks for the info.I just wanted the clarification by any chance there was a tweak to get this done.Well having two different classes is more like a design pattern.Anyway thanks for the info

Comment: @Ravisha: you can always hack `javac` to allow partial class definition, includes, etc. In fact, it's possible that such hack already exists. But no, standard Java doesn't allow this.

Comment: can u give any particular link w.r.t hacking javac