# Nested/Inner class in external file

Tags: java, file, external, nested-class

I have a class `MyClass` and an inner class `MyNestedClass` like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  ...
  public class MyNestedClass {
    ...
  }
}
```

Both classes are very long. Because of that i'd like to seperate them in two different files, without breaking the hierarchy. This is because the nested class shouldn't be visible to the programmer who uses MyClass.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764234/partial-classes-partial-class-file

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27284667/1190665
At least that's the best I came up with.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make the inner class package private which means that it will only be accessible from other classes in exactly the same package. This is also done quite frequently for hidden classes inside the standard JDK packages like `java.lang` or `java.util`.

in pkg/MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass {
  ...
}
```

in pkg/MyHiddenClass.java

```
class MyHiddenClass {

  final MyClass outer;

  MyHiddenClass( MyClass outer )
  {
      this.outer = outer;
  }
  ...
}
```

Now when you want to access methods or variables of the outer class you need to prefix them with `outer.` but you get essentially the same functionality as before when the reference to the outer instance was synthetically created by the compiler.

Comment: That's technically not still an inner class, though.

Comment: private attributes of `MyClass` won't be assessible from `MyHiddenClass`, and `MyHiddenClass` is protected, not private.

Answer (score 8):

No. Java source codes can not be split across multiple files. You'd need a construct similar to a partial class as in C#, which Java does not have.

Answer (score 8):

i think you have a god object or something like that, think in refactor your code

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: Thank you. This comment made me realize that I should redo my work. :)

Comment: PS, actually not. :) I just see that I need that respoinsability on my class.

Answer (score 5):

Objects of *inner* classes keep implicit references to the objects of the paren class.
If the *nested* class is not `static` (it is inner) you can not. But if the nested class does not need access to the parent's class instances directly and does not need access to the private fields, than should be ok to refactor, move the inner class out and do *not* declare it public (out of that package can not be accessed).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using cascade-jumper. A cascade-jumper is a abstract and non-static inner class that is defined anywhere else.

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass {
  public abstract class CascadeJumper {}
}
```

MyNestedClass

```
private class MyNestedClass extends MyClass.CascadeJumper {
  MyNestedClass(MyClass dollarOne) {
    dollarOne.super(); // yes, is possible!
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: I don't see how this could work. From `MyNestedClass` you will still only be able to access public methods and fields of `MyClass`, as from any other class.

Comment: @Alphaaa Nope, you can access private fields, private enums, private classes and private methods, private constructors, simply everything from `MyClass` in `MyNestedClass`! Try it!

Comment: I did and you can't. In fact even normal inner classes can't according to this: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_13.htm. The java compiler actually converts accesses to the outer class' private fields by generating package private methods and substitutes any direct field access with a call to one of these generated methods. All classes are in effect top level.

Comment: This doesn't work, though it looks cool. Private attributes means that they are only accessible from within the class. It doesn't work when my nested class is external. This may only work if I reference the necessary attributes for calculation of the outer class as protected attributes of the abstract nested super class.

Answer (score 1):

You could create abstract base classes that you extend in both.

However, if those classes are large, you might be better off re-evaluating your class design and see if you can refactor into classes which represent one concern each.

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous inner class.

```
public class External {
    public static Outer.Inner getExtendedInner(Outer outer) {
        return outer.new Inner() {
            // your extension
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).