# Add method to Generated class in Java

Tags: java, methods, categories, auto-generate

I have classes that are automatically generated in Java. I want to add a method to that class (in another file) so that I can add additional functionality without changing the generated file. The idea being that if I have to recreate the generated file, I won't lose my new functionality.

In Objective-c I know this is called categories, and in JavaScript you can append the object's prototype, but I am unaware of how to do this in Java or what it is called.

Comment: Why can't you change the generated file?

Comment: It's called extending a class. Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: @MattBall changing a generated file sucks if you ever have to re-generate it.

Comment: How are you generating the classes? XJC for JAXB classes or something else?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported in java.

[partial classes/partial class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764234/partial-classes-partial-class-file)

One thing you can do is inherit the generated class (if it is not final) and add your methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use composition, ie:

```
public class JasonString {
   String wrapped;

   public JasonString() {
      wrapped = new String();
   }

   public String toString() {
      return wrapped.toLowerCase().toString();
   }

   // other methods of wrapped class you're using should just call the corresponding method in wrapped.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the generated class you could try to extend it (if generated class is not final) and add new methods to sub-class... Java doesn't support dynamic attributes as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Itay I used to have auto-generated classes from Ibatis and the best way to go about with your problem is to extend all the generated classes and add the functionality that you want.